# If $a$ is the only element of order $2$ in a group, show that $a$ is in the center of the group.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

> If $a$ is the only element with order $2$ in a group $G$, then $a \in Z(G)$.

I'm studying for a test and I can't figure out how to prove it. What kind of methods might I try to solve this problem? I'd prefer suggestions rather than a proof, so that I can figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: conjugate elements have the same order.

Comment: Sadly, I am still lost.

Comment: If $|G|=2$, you're done. Otherwise, suppose $x$ is your element of order two. Then there exists some $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ such that $x\neq g$. Consider $gxg^{-1}$ (the "conjugate" of $x$ by $g$).

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out :D

Comment: OK Zachary, well done. I will give you another one to think about: let $G$ be a group with a unique element of order $n \gt 1$. Then $n=2$.