# if a is the only element of order k in G, then a is in the center of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a question from A Book Of Abstract Algebra. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646449/if-a-is-the-only-element-of-order-2-in-a-group-show-that-a-is-in-the-cent) which gives the same hint the book gives. Here are the hints given by the book:

1. $ord(a) = ord(bab^{-1})$
2. if $a = bab^{-1}$, then $ab = ba$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ commute).

I still don't understand how to solve this. $ord(a) = ord(bab^{-1})$ doesn't mean $a = bab^{-1}$, right?

Comment: You are right *in general*, but if $\text{ord}(a) = \text{ord}(bab^{-1})$ and $a$ is the *only* element of its order...

Comment: OH of course ... now I feel silly.

Comment: lol, It happens :)

Comment: if this happens then $k=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\operatorname{ord}(a) = \operatorname{ord}(bab^{-1})$, then since $a$ is the only element which has the same order as $a$ (unique by its order), then $bab^{-1}$ must equal $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $ord(a)=k$ then $ord(bab^{-1})=k$. Since $a$ is the  **only** element of order $k$ in the group, it means that any element of order $k$ must be equal to $a$.